# Can I Edit (make dynamic) the Subject of an Exp:resso Store Order Confirmation Email Template?

Tags: add-on, expresso-store

How can I alter the subject of an order confirmation email? My client does different promotions throughout the year, and I'm looking to put a variable in the subject, if possible. For example, right now "Cool Company Order Confirmation - Spring Promotion", and then later in the year "Cool Company Order Confirmation - Fall Promotion"

The alternative is to rename the Email Subject periodically, but I'd rather pull a promotion name from the checkout form that generated the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Store custom fields in the email subject, such as:

```
CONFIRMATION: Publication Order - {order_custom9}
```

We're doing this for a client. The data for the field is filled in by a hidden input, for us. But I imagine there maybe other ways to submit it to Store.

Since your promotions aren't always available, you probably want to use an {if statement on whether the promotion is submit to the custom field, and make sure the custom field gets the dash, as well

```
- Fall Promotion
```

So it would only display if the data was submitted to the field.